# Making a HttpClient request in java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am creating a data downloader which has been giving me problems since using httpClient

This code append all variables needed to the URL :

```
   private void createOpenSession() {
   String params = new StringBuilder()
           .append("?u=").append(this.user)
           .append("&p=").append(this.password)
           .append("&q=").append(this.qualifier)
           .toString();
   this.openSession = new HttpGet(this.target + params);
```

}

Whenever i call the `openSession`, it print out the header in a simple way(Just what i need it to do)...

```
   public void start() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException  {

        try {
            HttpResponse response = this.httpClient.execute(this.openSession);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                try {
                    String responseContent = this.readResponse(response);
                    System.out.println(responseContent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }}
            finally {
               createCloseSession();
            }
        }
```

This Prints a Single Line `Thisdude:coole3r`, but when i make another request that prints long line, It always bring this error:

```
    Exception in thread main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP request may not be null
    at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at com.si.data.client.ProxyClient1.start(ProxyClient1.java:72)
    at com.si.data.client.IpcClient.main(IpcClient.java:136)
```

This is the Second Request that gives error:

```
    private void createCurrencyPairsRequest(String currencyPairs) throws IOException {
    if (this.sessionId == null) {
        this.refreshSessioId();
    }
    String params = new StringBuilder()
            .append("?id=").append(this.sessionId)
            .append("&c=").append(currencyPairs)//The Pairs is an array
            .append("&f=").append(this.format)
            .toString();
    this.requestCurrencies = new HttpGet(this.target + params);
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong in the `currencyPairsRequest()` ?
Thanks for your time taken..

Answer (score 0):

I Solved It By Debugging the `currencyPairsRequest()`..
This is how i solved this...
I changed the `currencyPairsRequest()` return type from `void()` to `HttpGet`.

```
   private HttpGet createCurrencyPairsRequest(String currencyPairs) throws IOException {
       if (this.sessionId == null) {
           this.refreshSessioId();
       }
       String params = new StringBuilder()
               .append("?id=").append(this.sessionId)
               .append("&c=").append(currencyPairs)
               .append("&f=").append(this.format)
               .toString();
       this.requestCurrencies = new HttpGet(this.target + params);
    return requestCurrencies;
   }
```

Then, I Called the `currencyPairsRequest() using :

```
System.out.println(requestCurrencies);
```

from the `main()` before initiating any request...
And, It Printed `null`, which means i've been sending a `null` request since yesterday..
So, I changed my request by not using `requestCurrencies`, but by calling the function itself and returning its value...

Thanks All..